# What font is Windows 10 using to display exotic unicode characters that other programs don't?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, unicode

In windows 10 search bar, in Edge and even in other browsers like Chrome, exotic Unicode characters, such as ... from Phoenician or other dead languages, are displaying nicely for me.

However, most other programs (Word, Notes, Anki...) can't render them. Windows will also fail to display these characters in file names.

I searched in the web for some Unicode fonts that have the Phoenician to no avail. How can I get the fonts that Windows is already using in some places?

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, you can right click on those glyphs and select *Inspect Element*. Then go to the *font* tab somewhere on the right, to see the actual font (Edge has a similar option). This font seems to be *Segoe UI Historic*.

When copying text from the browser to Word, the font information is lost somehow, so you'll have to select it manually.